# How to fix "[mobx] deprecated: `mobx.map` is deprecated" error when the error sims to be in mobx-firebase-store package?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, mobx

I am going through a lynda.com course and this is the code that I have

```
import firebase from 'firebase'
import MobxFirebaseStore from 'mobx-firebase-store'

const config = {
    // I pasted the info from google firebase here
  }

export default class SettingsStore extends MobxFirebaseStore {
    constructor() {
        firebase.initializeApp(config)
        super(firebase.database().ref())

        this.splashTime = 5000
        this.splashImg = require('../../images/splash.jpg')
    }
    get SplashTime(){
        return this.splashTime
    }
    get SplashImg() {
        return this.splashImg
    }

}
```

That's the only place re refer to `mobx-firebase-store`

The error I get is that `mobx.map` is deprecated, use `new ObservableMap` or `mobx.observable.map`

`mobx.map` is use on line 244 of the `mobx-firebase-store` package, I tried to simply change `mobx.map` to `mobx.observable.map` but nothing happened.

I read the readme file of `mobx-firebase-store` and the code is nothing like my class. I just don't want to go off the videos as I have no idea how I would get back in.

Is the code above totally deprecated, or is there anything I can do to move forward with the course?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really solve it, but it's more of a warning than an error.

`mobx-firebase-store` has `mobx` as a `peerDependency` and uses `map`. When `map` is removed, it is up to you to use a version of `mobx` that still has it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the mobx-firebase-store author and have just released a version -- 1.0.1 -- that works with mobx 3.1.3 and the new mobx.observable.map.

Answer (score 0):

@relidon The problem you're having has to do with the fact that mobx deprecated a feature (mobx.map) which mobx-firebase-store relies on. mobx-firebase-store hasn't been updated in a while, so to get the project working, simply revert to mobx version 2.6.3 to be able to move forward with the dinder course. Obviously this isn't a good solution for "real" apps.